# Convert nested map to nested list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Assume I have a class Level with nested Levels i.e.

```
public class Level {
    private Map<String, Level> childLevels
}
```

I want to convert this class into the following:

```
public class ListLevel {
    private List<ListLevel> childLevels
}
```

ChildLevels are not necessarily instantiated and may be null. I start with a `Map<String, Level>` and I want to convert this into a `List<ListLevel>` by discarding the key of every Map entry.

I've tried the code below but it's not quite there. edit: below code won't work with a new ListLevel class

```
private static List<Level> convertToList(Map<String, Level> levelMap){
    return levelMap.values().stream()
        .filter(i -> i.getChildLevels() != null)
        .flatMap(i -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(i), convertToList(i.getChildLevels()).stream()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Any suggestions?

edit: to clarify, I want to convert all nested maps to lists but maintain the same nested structure

Comment: Not clear. Do you want just the list of child-Levels of a single Level, or a flat list of all the Levels below the "root" (if so, intermediate and leafs, or just leafs?), or actually create a nested list mirroring the tree structure of Level?

Comment: The third - created a nested list mirroring the tree structure of Level. Essentially re-creating the Map but replacing Map with List at all levels of the tree and ignoring all Map keys.

Comment: Guess you will need another class `ListLevel` with `List<Level> childLevels` then. It would be easier, though, to use the existing `Level` class and just ignore the keys, or add another method to get the non-null values as a list.

Comment: Ah you're right, will update the question.

Comment: @villabilla Then you have a root level object only right ?

Comment: No, you would still have List<LevelList>, each LevelList containing it's own List<LevelList>, in the same way that you start off with a Map<String, Level>, each Level with it's own Map<String, Level>.

Comment: ListLevel and Level are two different class both have same field and do you have converter for Level to ListLevel conversion ?

Comment: Yup you can I assume there is one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `values()` of `Map` like `levelMap.values().stream()` since you want the values of map.

```
private static List<Level> convertToList(Map<String, Level> levelMap){
    return levelMap.values().stream()
        .filter(i -> i.getChildLevels() != null)
        .flatMap(i -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(i), convertToList(i.getChildLevels()).stream()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**After question Updated:**

```
private static List<ListLevel> convertToList(Map<String, Level> levelMap){
    if(levelMap == null) return null;
    return levelMap.values().stream()
        .map(i -> convertLevelToListLevel(i, convertToList(i.getChildLevels())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here `ListLevel convertLevelToListLevel(Level level, List<ListLevel> childListLevels)` is converter for `Level` to `ListLevel` conversion as mention in comment OP already have.

Comment: Right, but not an answer to the question anymore...

Comment: Sorry I asked a bad question, I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: @Turo I will update question changed only 3 minute ago

Comment: @villabilla answer  updated